# jQuery - Closest TD values after searching or sorting

Tags: jquery, html, datatables

I have a modal window that pops up and displays a list of vendors in a table.  Each row has a 'select' button that selects the data from that row and then updates some form input fields on the parent page with the values of the TD's.

This works fine until I use the data tables search or column sorting first.
If I search or sort this table and then use the select button, no data is assigned.

Again, this works fine, it only breaks once I do any search or sorting using the built in data tables search / sort first.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".select-vendor").click(function () {
        var $row = $(this).closest("tr");    // Find the row
        var $tds = $row.find("td");
        console.log($row);
        $.each($tds, function () {
            document.forms["myForm"]["vendNameAddr"].value = $row.find('#vendNameAddrSearch').val();
            document.forms["myForm"]["vendPhone"].value = $row.find('#vendPhoneSearch').val();
            document.forms["myForm"]["vendEmail"].value = $row.find('#vendEmailSearch').val();
        });
    });
});
```

```html
echo '<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="vendNameAddrSearch" id="vendNameAddrSearch" value="' . $vendorinfo . '"><input type="hidden" name="vendPhoneSearch" id="vendPhoneSearch" value="' . $res->phonenumber . '"><input type="hidden" name="vendEmailSearch" id="vendEmailSearch" value="' . $res->emailaddress . '"><button type="button" class="select-vendor" onclick="document.getElementById(\'vendorModal\').style.display=\'none\'">Select</button></td><td>' . $res->vendorname . '</td><td>' . $res->address1 . '</td><td>' . $res->address2 . '</td><td>' . $res->city . '</td><td>' . $res->state . '</td><td>' . $res->zip . '</td><td>' . $res->country . '</td></tr>';
```

Comment: try to create a working example link ( like fiddle or here with dummy data) so that problem can be reproduce and we will assist you on that

Comment: I second that.. if you're using datatables, maybe show some datatables code..

Answer (score 0):

You likely have repeated IDs. Change all IDs to class and use the relative addressing you started

```js
$(".select-vendor").on("click", function() {
  $('#vendorModal').hide();
  var $row = $(this).closest("tr"); // Find the row
  $row.find(".vendNameAddr").val($row.find('.vendNameAddrSearch').val());
  $row.find(".vendPhone").val($row.find('.vendPhoneSearch').val());
  $row.find(".vendEmail").val($row.find('.vendEmailSearch').val());
});
```

```html
<tr>
  <td><input type="hidden" name="vendNameAddrSearch" class="vendNameAddrSearch" value="$vendorinfo">
    <input type="hidden" name="vendPhoneSearch" class="vendPhoneSearch" value="$res-phonenumber">
    <input type="hidden" name="vendEmailSearch" class="vendEmailSearch" value="$res-emailaddress">
    <button type="button" class="select-vendor">Select</button></td>
  <td>$res-vendorname</td>
  <td>$res-address1</td>
  <td>$res-address2</td>
  <td>$res-city</td>
  <td>$res-state</td>
  <td>$res-zip</td>
  <td>$res-country</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

figured out the issue.  Once i wrapped the onclick method with:

"fnDrawCallback": function( oSettings ) {}

It now works as it gets the new row data after each redraw.